# Accessing Other Entities Attributes in Dynamics CRM/365 Forms with javaScript

Tags: javascript, crm, microsoft-dynamics, jscript, dynamics-365-sales

This function `buttonBuzz()` works inside the Forms of the Entities Account, Contacts and Leads. But not in the Opportunity form.
Mainly because there is no `telephone1` attribute. There is however a Contact entity added with "Quick View" in a section with a telephonenumber inside.

[image: View of the Opportunity Form w/ Contact Quick View marked in red]

I think it can be accessed with the `telephone1` as well just not with `Xrm.page`

**Any ideas how i can grab the attribute from inside the "quick view"?**

I dont know if the "Quick view" window is a form of an iFrame. And if it is i have no clue how to access it with the `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("telephone1").getValue();`

```
function buttonBuzz(exObj) {
var phoneNumber;

// Here i store the "telephone1" Attribute from the current .page
phoneNumber = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("telephone1").getValue();

if (phoneNumber != null) {      **Sends phonenumber**           } ...
```

Comment: And btw the form is just filled with Dummy information. So nothing confidential is shown here of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Views display data from a record selected in a lookup field, in this case a Contact. You can query data from related records using the OData endpoint.

You first need to get the Guid of the record selected:

```
var contactId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("parentcontactid")[0].id || null;
```

You would then need to send a [SDK.REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427(v=crm.7).aspx) request, passing parameters for the Id of the record (`contactId`), `entityName` and the `columns`:

```
var entityName = "Contact";
var columns = "Address1_Telephone1, FirstName, LastName";    

SDK.REST.retrieveRecord(contactId, entityName, columns, null, function(result) {
    // Success, logic goes here.
    var address1_Telephone1 = result.Address1_Telephone1;
}, function(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
});
```

---

As well as your JavaScript file, you would need to include the SDK.REST.js file that is  included in the [MS CRM SDK download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50032) within your Opportunity form libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull that field up from the Contact into the Opportunity by creating a Calculated Field, setting it equal to `parentcontactid.telephone1`

Put the field on the form, and you'll be able to `.getAttribute()` it like any other Opportunity field (being Calculated, it updates itself whenever the source changes).

Comment: Clever and, so far, it seems to work for me. [Using a QuickView for this was problematic for me because the field concerned had a form-specific OnChange event handler in its own entity which was getting invoked and failing]